# Picker items are not properly rendering on the screen - React Native Picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react native application and I want to add a picker to my project. I added the `Picker` from `@react-native-picker/picker'`. I created all the picker items and the value is changing but the labels are not changing for some reason and it is not displaying any of the labels.

Here is the code:

```
<View style={styles.bnbcounter}>
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>Days Listed</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Picker 
              selectedValue={daysListed}
              onValueChange={(selected) => {setDaysListed(selected)}}
            >
              <Picker.Item label="Java" value={"java"} />
              <Picker.Item label="1 Day" value={'1'}/>
              <Picker.Item label="1 Week" value={'7'}/>
              <Picker.Item label="2 Weeks" value={'14'}/>
              <Picker.Item label="1 Month" value={'30'}/>
              <Picker.Item label="3 Months" value={'90'}/>  
              <Picker.Item label="6 Months" value={'6m'}/>
              <Picker.Item label="1 Year" value={'12m'}/>
              <Picker.Item label="2 Years" value={'24m'}/>
              <Picker.Item label="3 Years" value={'36m'}/>
            </Picker>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Here is what is showing:
[image: screen]

Answer (score 3):

```
 <Picker
       style={{marginHorizontal:20}} 
            >
              <Picker.Item label="Java" value={"java"} />
              <Picker.Item label="1 Day" value={'1'}/>
              <Picker.Item label="1 Week" value={'7'}/>
                  </Picker>
```

> see my expo code its working fine.
> https://snack.expo.dev/@muhammadabdullahrishi/picker-component